# How do I reduce the scannable area in my app?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera, zxing

I've written an app which is used to scan barcodes in a paper-based product catalogue which can then be ordered.

The app is written with Xamarin and is using ZXing barcode scanner.

Unfortunately the barcodes are a bit small in the catalogue and very close to each other, which means sometimes more than 1 barcode will fit in the scannable rectangle and leads to the wrong barcode being picked up. It does not appear as though it begins scanning in the middle, it can sometimes pick something up above or below the middle.

I am using the following code base: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/src/ZXing.Net.Mobile/Android

I have managed to reduce the size of the overlay rectangle in GetFramingRect(), however this is obviously presentational only and does not modify the actual area that is being scanned.

In the surfaceview class I have used setPreviewSize and setPictureSize to reduce the height/width to mirror the size of the rectangle overlay (hardcoded in testing to ensure exact same sizes), yet the app is still scanning from way outside the rectangle.

I've been searching for days on a way to do this but have not been able to find anything that has worked.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not.